# Precipitate Sodium Hypochlorite from tap water before distillation

Tags: distillation

Is there a fairly simple way to precipitate Sodium Hypochlorite from tap water before I distill it? Or, second best, a way to neutralize it?

Comment: Hmm, is this unclear? Could the CV'ers enlighten me on what detail this is missing? I think John is looking for a process that precipitates Chlorinated agents.

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sodium hypochlorite is not carried over into water by distillation.  Instead, at high (~100°C) it [decomposes](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j150327a013), primarily to sodium chloride (i.e. table salt) and oxygen gas, but also possibly to trace amounts of chlorate.

You could neutralize the hypochlorite by mixture with stoichiometric amounts of hydrogen peroxide, which cause immediate release of oxygen gas, a reaction which occurs even at room temperature.

Comment: This is helpful. If no one knows how to precipitate the solution, I will mark this as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: You should be aware that if you use excess H2O2 instead of the sociometric amount, then you will have a problem with H2O2 contamination, both in the crude water and possibly in the distillate.